# Namespacing Functions (PHP)

Tags: php, namespaces, silex

I would like to "namespace" a collection of functions and call them. The reason is that I'd like to keep the function names the same across multiple files (and thus distinguish them by namespace). My below implementation yields a **"Call to undefined function..."** error:

**main.php**:

```
//located in /src/main.php 
namespace Roles;
use functions\Form; //doesn't seem to work
use functions\View; //doesn't seem to work
use Silex\Application; //works 
use Silex\ControllerProviderInterface; //works

class mainfct {
//calls respective functions in the namespaces
  Form\a();
  Form\b();

  View\a();
  View\b();
}
```

**form.php**:

```
//located in /src/functions/form.php
namespace Form;
function main() { a(); b();};
function a() {...};
function b() {...};
```

**view.php**:

```
//located in /src/functions/view.php
namespace View;
function main() { a(); b();};
function a() {...not necessarily same code as above...};
function b() {...not necessarily same code...};
```

The above doesn't seem to work. What's the best way to implement this?

Comment: Can you explain what `The above doesn't seem to work.` means? We don't have a glass globe to find that out. Do you get any error?

Comment: "Call to undefined function" error. Theoretically is it supposed to work?

Comment: Do you use `use {namespace name here};` somewhere before? It could be you're not on the global namespace anymore. Try with prepending a backslash before the namespace name.

Comment: This is better supported in PHP 5.6 http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php.  `use function ...`.  Im not sure if that is what you are looking for though.

Comment: I edited my post to include more information. Hopefully it's more clear.

Comment: Seems like these would be better suited as a class or group of, then you can use inheritance and keep it DRY.  Whats the diffrence between `$Form->b()` and `$View->b()` instead of `\Form\b()` and `\View\b()`.  If you don't want the instance of then make them static `Form::b()` `View::b()`.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're not using PHP 5.6 -- prior to that importing of functions or constants (view `use`) [was unimplemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412104/why-is-importing-a-php-function-into-the-current-namespace-unsupported) in the language.

Re: your update -- unlike the standard included library in languages like ruby or python, PHP namespaces are **not** tied to the filename/path.  You're trying to import `functions\Form`

```
use functions\Form; //doesn't seem to work
```

However, you don't have a namespace named `\functions\Form`, you have namespace named `\Form`

```
namespace Form;
```

To get this to work, you'd want to

```
use Form;
```

or

```
namespace functions\Form;
```

Also, in case its not obvious, for reasons historic and frustrating, PHP namespaces do **nothing** to include/require/autoload PHP files.  That's a separate system in PHP.

Comment: My `main.php` file is actually implementing `use` for another namespace (not shown for less clutter), and that works.

Comment: I also had to `require` the files.

Answer (score 1):

Namespace is a way to avoid the same name function/class error.

It didn't help you do any include.

You should use include in main.php just like:


`include('form.php');
include('view.php');`

Or use spl_autoload_register function, see http://php.net/manual/zh/function.spl-autoload-register.php;

Or use psr0 psr4 with composer, see https://getcomposer.org/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to add `require` statements to load the files `form.php` and `view.php`. Also, I had to "use" the namespaces by `use Form;`.

I had to be wary of any references to classes in my namespaces. For example, `throw new Exception()` would have to be `throw new \Exception()` to be in the right namespace.